# Foursquare API - Disable Suggested Locations

Tags: foursquare

We are trying to pull all bars and restaurants from the foursquare API for a specific area. However we are noticing only locations that foursquare recommends are showing up. We are not interested in that, we are interested in every bar in the area. Is there a way to disable the suggested bars so that all bars show up at once?

Thanks.

Comment: how about at least posting the api call you made so we can see what you're doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You should be using the [venues/search](https://developer.foursquare.com/docs/venues/search) API for this - it sounds like you're using the venues/explore API.

Note that with any API call, you can only retrieve 50 venues at a time. There isn't a straightforward way to get every bar within a search area.